# Kubernetes services to be exposed to local machine

Tags: networking, docker, kubernetes, vmware, kubeadm

I am running my kubernetes cluster using kubeadm (local using VMWare VMs). As a part of installation , I have installed Weave Network Adapter to establish relation between master and slave.

I could able to create the pods and services successfully. Even, could able to get the application using the private IP that kubeadm has given.

The problem is , I am not able to access the same application using my system although network is shared with VMs and my local machine. This is what is expected. The main reason being private network.

I want to access the application in my local machine which is outside of the private kubernates networks.

**Point to be remembered :** I am hosting everything on my local machine using VMWare VMs.

Can anybody help me on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport). I had the same issue when I tried everything locally. You'll need to use `--type=NodePort`

For example I've created a deployment:

```
./cluster/kubectl.sh run my-jenkins --image=jenkins:1.651.1 --replicas=1 --port=8080 –-namespace=jenkins
```

I check the pod

```
kubectl --namespace=jenkins get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-jenkins-1908062973-7b44z   1/1       Running   0          24s
```

My deployment created a pod + replicaSet for me in the deploymentconfig.
Now I want to create a service above my pod

```
./cluster/kubectl.sh expose rs my-jenkins-1908062973 --port=80 --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort --name=jenkins-service --namespace=jenkins
```

Thanks to the `--type=NodePort` I'm able to visit my service also locally

If you set the type field to "NodePort", the Kubernetes master will allocate a port from a flag-configured range (default: 30000-32767), and each Node will proxy that port (the same port number on every Node) into your Service. That port will be reported in your Service’s spec.ports[*].nodePort field.

Comment: Thanks . This works for me . As the node port will vary from 30000-32767, do we have any mechanism for load balancing the same so that we should not look into the dynamic port any point of time ?

If Yes, Can you please help me to find out the solution for the same...

Comment: I did not try it but the documentation which I've provided in the answer tells this about it: "If you want a specific port number, you can specify a value in the nodePort field, and the system will allocate you that port or else the API transaction will fail (i.e. you need to take care about possible port collisions yourself). The value you specify must be in the configured range for node ports."